# java pattern accept string with space

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to the string before and after a keyword using pattern and matcher. I currently have this code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w.]+)\\W+=\\W+([\\w.]+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("something = 1.21 and another = 2 && something else == 123?");
        while (m.find())
            System.out.printf("'%s', '%s'%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
```

output:

> ```
> 'something', '1.21'
> 'another', '2'
> 'else', '123'
> ```

I am trying to pass in " = " only instead of just "=" cause I don't wan't the "==" to appear in the list.

whenever I try this, nothing at all will be printed out.

desired output:

> ```
> 'something', '1.21'
> 'another', '2'
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your current pattern is that `\W+` matches whitespace *and* any other non word character, including `=`.  This is causing the false match of the `==` term.  I recommend just using `\s*` to represent the separator between the variable name/value and symbol.  Here is a slightly updated version of your script:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w.]+)\\s*=\\s+([\\w.]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("something = 1.21 and another = 2 && something else == 123?");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("'%s', '%s'%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

This outputs:

```
'something', '1.21'
'another', '2'
```

Comment: I know what s means, I read the manual. s is A whitespace character, short for [ \t\n\x0b\r\f] but don't know what it means when adding a * and + next to it

Comment: Well I'm trying to be flexible, and assuming that perhaps there might not be any whitespace in between `=` and the LHS\RHS.

Comment: last question please: How can I achieve it if the input is something = something(); and I want the output to contain the (); part?

Comment: Well the general pattern `\S+\s*=\s*\S+` might work.

Comment: It doesn't :/ I tried this as you said Pattern.compile("([\\w.]+)\\S+\\s*=\\s*\\S+([\\w.]+)");

Comment: That's not what I suggested.  I suggested: `Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\s*=\\s*(\\S+)")`

Comment: this does re print the ==

Comment: any idea for this?